# Pearson Correlation Result

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have been carrying out some Pearson correlations. In some of the outcome tables I get the following results inside instead of a correlation value:

"**NA**", "**NaN**", "**-Inf*****"

I found a link that stated NaN indicates there is no correlation between the variables (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/506464-getting-a-nan-in-correlation-coefficient).

> The NaN, in this case, is interpreted as no correlation between the two variables.  The correlation describes how much one variable changes as the other variable changes.  That requires both variables to change.

[image]

As shown in the image the issue occurs with variables "sand", "slit", "clay". These variables were a single value measurement in the dataset while the rest of variables in the example ("tc", "soc", "tn") consisted of triplicate measurements within the dataset. I am not sure if this is part of the issue leading to these non-numerical results.

I wanted to ask if each of these results which all appear within the same table mean the same. I hope this makes sense. If a chunk of my data is required to make it easier to understand my query please let me know.

(06/12/2022) - **Update**
Below there is the code being used. Also this data extract does not have any missing values but the overall data set does have a few missing values. However I noticed the issue seems to only occur with "sand", "silt" and "clay".

```
# Library
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)

# Data subset
dk1 <-structure(list(tc = c(1.38, 1.76, 1.36, 1.48, 1.25, 1.48),
                     soc = c(0.618, 0.951, 1.08, 1.11, 0.756, 1.38),
                     tn = c(0.104, 0.137, 0.11, 0.112, 0.112, 0.106),
                     sand = c(96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96),
                     silt = c(2.5,2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5),
                     clay = c(1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6),
                     ph = c(6.77, 7.25, 6.69, 7.14, 6.63, 7.18)),
                row.names = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
View(dk1)

# Correlation table
dk1corr <- rcorr(as.matrix(dk1), type = c("pearson"))
dk1corr

# Correlations coefficients and p value extract
ccr.dk1corr<-dk1corr$r
ccp.dk1corr<-dk1corr$P
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data with `dput()`

Comment: In addition to a sample of your data, include the code you used. Does you data have missing values?

Comment: @ViníciusFélix please see example attached

Comment: @dcarlson my overall dataset does have missing values but the example provided does not as the issue seems to appear with only sand, silt and clay

Comment: They are perfectly correlated because each one is constant. Sand is always 96, silt 2.5, and clay 1.6. You may also run into problems because the three variables will always sum to 100 percent (`rowSums(dk1[, 4:6])`).

Comment: Thank you so much @dcarlson Is this why when correlated to other parameters instead of numerical numbers it shows NaN, NA or -Inf***? Will the best way of justifying to exclude the correlation of sand, silt and clay be the value is constant so correlations are perfect and therefore not a real result?

Comment: Or just do not include one in your correlation matrix. If you know two, you can compute the third. If sand dominates your samples, exclude it and focus on silt and clay. There are other ways to handle compositional data like this, but that would be a question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or a quick search on the internet.

Comment: @dcarlson thank you so much for your help! I will be doing some reading on it! :)